# If using Jwt token, there is a need of Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I was trying to create a Spring Microservice Project which makes use of the Jwt Bearer token. I have found this interesting resource: https://springframework.guru/jwt-authentication-in-spring-microservices-jwt-token/.

The issue here is that I do not see it implemented with Spring Security. I've been thinking about the code and I realized that this is a good alternative (even in prod) for authenticating WITHOUT using Spring Security.

Is this correct? Is it logically correct to provide this type of protection to the application, without Spring Security?

Moreover, I was thinking of the following pattern:

1. CoreAuthorizationService => containing all of the User, Roles, User_Roles repositories, and the service with the actual login / register implementations.
2. AuthService => containing the controller of the auth which calls the functions defined in the CoreAuthorisationService. (I added the coreAuthorizationService in the pom.xml file)
3. Any other service => containing the filter classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since most of the answers here our either misinformed or outdated i will answer this with some references.

As of time of writing (november 2023) [oauth2 has deprecated](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics#section-2.1.2) what is called the *IMPLICIT GRANT* which in short was the flow were you authenticated directly with an *issuer*  using a *username* and *password* and directly got issued a token to the client due to this flow has been found to be vulnerable to *access token* leakage and *access token replay* attacks.

Take notice that the deprecation mentions tokens, this means both JWTs and opague tokens.

JWTs has since long been been not recommended to use as a replacement for sessions, or session tokens, since there are no ways of storing a token securely in the browser, OWASP has [recommendation against storing tokens in browsers](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/JSON_Web_Token_for_Java_Cheat_Sheet.html#token-storage-on-client-side). they also have several recommendations for instance not using JWTs unless you actually server side store some reference to the JWT since tokens can not be logged out. SO you cant *log out all devices* or logout a token that has been stolen.

Several instances recommend against JWTs as session tokens:

https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/08/17/why-jwts-suck-as-session-tokens

https://redis.com/blog/json-web-tokens-jwt-are-dangerous-for-user-sessions/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JdGOb7AxUo0

[http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/](http://cryto.net/%7Ejoepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/)

[http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/19/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions-part-2-why-your-solution-doesnt-work/](http://cryto.net/%7Ejoepie91/blog/2016/06/19/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions-part-2-why-your-solution-doesnt-work/)

There is no such implementation (showed in the linked tutorial in the question) in spring security, because it is not recommended to do such authentication. **So there is has been an active choice to not have it**.

But why do so many recommend that, well its a long story, but mostly that security is hard, someone found a way to write security that seemed easy and "sort of worked" and then others copied it.

So how should you build security?

Well it all depends on what your demands are.

### Small application

Session based, FormLogin using cookies, with *httpOnly* and *Secured* flags set, use *CORS* and *CSRF* tokens.

### Mid sized

Separate issuer/authorization server, build a BFF (backend for frontend), have cookies between BFF and frontend, the BFF authenticates against the issues using Authorization code flow with PKCE and stores the JWT in the backend, never hands out the JWT to the client. use CORS and CSRF

### Large application

Same as above but this time follow the OpenIDConnect standard, hand out AT-token, RT-Token ID-Token all as cookies to the frontend instead of a cookie. Have several resource servers, supply the AT token from the fontend in requests and have a proxy that will exchange the cookie token for a JWT, the JWT is used only within the corporate network and never is exposed out on the internet.

Security isnt hard, as long as people read the standards and actually follows the standards and are not trying to invent custom home made security all the time. There is a reason there are standards, because they have been proven to be secure.

Answer (score 3):

It is perfectly valid to do it if you just need JWT authentication.But spring security provides much more security feature than authentication. For example, one common feature is authorization which allows you to protect an endpoint or method such that it can only be invoked by the user who has enough permissions (e.g. using `@PreAuthorize`) , and other features such as [CORS](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/integrations/cors.html#page-title) support, [HttpFirewall](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/exploits/firewall.html#page-title) and [CSRF](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/features/exploits/csrf.html) support etc.

So if you just need to do JWT authentication now, no problem and go ahead. And consider to migrate to spring security when come to the point you need the extra features that are already provided by spring-secrutiy rather than reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and no.

Yes, because Spring Security has a reputation for being unnecessary complex, so some teams avoid it altogether and write custom code for auth. In the past 5 years or so, most [brownfield](https://blog.fosketts.net/2012/12/18/brownfield-terrible-antonym-greenfield/) projects I have worked on have avoided Spring Security altogether.

And no, because then you may be unable use many convenience features provided by Spring Security [[1]](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/index.html) [[2]](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/method-security.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I know that Spring Security provides a lot of functionality (too complex to be honest, indeed, :)) ), but as long as you make some helper functions, such as @ Preauthorise / @ Secured, and much more, I guess it will be fine. What about the structure of the microservices? Do you think it is a good way of approaching the situation?

Comment: yes you can try to implement somethings similar to `@PreAuthorize `, but it is not easy to do it. Most probably in the end i guess you may think why don't simply just use the existing one provided by spring-security and waste time to implement it by yourself..

Comment: Just saw your comment. I think it’s worth learning it (may the Spring gods help you in your odyssey ;) and then using it in micro services.

Answer (score -2):

with jwt you might get authentication then how about authorization which only spring security provides.